# Random variable Logic

Tags: variables, random, logic, jmeter

I would like to test an app with random variable logic through JMeter. it is voting application.

Flow: Login-voting-ReVoting-Logout for 250 users

Problem:  I have to vote 1 person out of 3 members and again I have to re-vote to another person. I have defined vote members id in user defined variables,so first I have used bean shell code for the first vote. here is the code.(Beanshell1)

```
import java.util.Random;

String[] categories = (vars.get("categories")).split(",");

int idx = new Random().nextInt(categories.length);
String category = (categories[idx]);

vars.put("rnd_cat",category);
```

for re-voting, I want to exclude the previous vote member id, so I have used below code for that (Beanshell2)

```
while(category==rnd_cat)
{
     String[] categories = (vars.get("categories")).split(",");

     int idx2 = new Random().nextInt(categories.length);
     category = (categories[idx2]);
}
```

but I am getting void in the response.

Answer (score 0):

Beanshell knows nothing regarding what `rnd_cat` is. Also comparing strings via `==` operator isn't a very good idea. Amend your "Beanshell2" as follows:

```
while(category.equals(vars.get("rnd_cat"))
{
     String[] categories = (vars.get("categories")).split(",");

     int idx2 = new Random().nextInt(categories.length);
     String category = (categories[idx2]);
}
```

And consider switching to [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language as it is highly recommended way of doing scripting in JMeter as it evidenced by [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) article.

Another good option which doesn't require scripting at all is [__chooseRandom()](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/) function available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/)

Comment: I am getting illegal character execpetion..can we pass variable from beanshell1 to beanshell2?

Comment: If they're in the same thread group - `vars.put()` and `vars.get()`. If in the separate - `props.put()` and `props.get()`.  It is impossible to say anything obvious without seeing screenshot of your test plan and full Beanshell code